# Cannot convert 'System.__ComObject' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

The code below gives me the error: `cannot convert COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem`.

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbk;

workbk = app.Workbooks.Open(savePath);
//ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
foreach (var list in workbk.Sheets)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add((ListItem)list);
}
```

Why am I receiving the error?

Answer (score 3):

As the error implies, the worksheet from the `Sheets` collection is not a `ListItem`. You need to do some sort of conversion in between (for example, grabbing the cell values, or the sheet name, or something else)